# multiple selectors not seems to work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following HTML

```
<div id="finalTree">  
<ul>  
 <li class="last" style="display: list-item;">  
 <a id="DataSheets" href="#">Data Sheets</a> 
</li></u>...........</div>
```

and I am first hiding all these li and then trying to show those li which match to selector. Here is my JavaScript. Here filterData is id of links.

```
function filterLeftNavTree(filterData){
    jQuery("ul.treeview").find("li").hide();
    var selectors =[];
    if(filterData.indexOf("|")!=-1){
        var filterData = filterData.split("|");
        for(i=0;i<filterData.length;i++){
            selectors.push('#'+filterData[i]);
        }  
        var filtered = selectors.join(',');
        $(filtered ).show();

    }else{  

        $('#'+filterData+).show();
    }  }
```

the last two line doesn't works...
any one can tell me what can be possible reason. Actually I tried to show li with `:has, :contains, find().filter()` but all these are taking too much time if I have large tree.

Do I am trying to show it by using multiple selector, but it's not showing any thing. Any alternative having faster way to show it will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have (aside from the syntax error @verrerby mentioned) *should* be working, but why not cut down on that code a bit?

You can slim things down by adding the `#` on every element after the first as part of the [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), this also greatly simplifies the logic.  You can reduce it down to:

```
function filterLeftNavTree(filterData) {
  $("ul.treeview li").hide();
  $('#'+filterData.split('|').join(',#')).show();
}
```

Also note the change removing [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/), it's faster in browser that support it to use a single selector, and just as fast in all the others.

The only other *possible* reason I see for your code not working is `jQuery` is used for the hide and `$` is used on the show, is it possible `$` refers to something else? (e.g. ptototype?)  To test just replace `$` with `jQuery` on the [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) call.

Comment: it's not working in this way but if i am using $(':has(#'+filterData+')').show() , then it's working but results are coming very slowly

Comment: @Vivek - is the ID not on the actual element? With `$("ul.treeview li").hide();` you're hiding all children, at *all* levels, it seems like you need: `$('#'+filterData.split('|').join(',#')).parents('li').andSelf().show();`

Comment: @nick-yes!!!i need this thing..now it's working like charm..how can i missed it?any way thanks a lot nick...

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra `+'` in the last statement, and you could do it in multiple statements instead of one (the `#{id}` selector is very fast):

```
if(filterData.indexOf("|")!=-1){
    var filterData = filterData.split("|");
    for(i=0;i<filterData.length;i++){
        $('#'+filterData[i]).show();
    }  

}else{  

    $('#'+filterData).show();
}
```

Comment: that + was typing mistake i also tried this before this code...but response same. and while showing in loop.it will take more time.performance issue

Comment: are you sure it will take more time? i would suspect jQuery would do pretty much the same behind the scenes. if this does not work, have you tried to inspect your filterData list, because I can't really see any reasons why this shouldn't work.

Comment: yes it's working but not as fast as other option can work..nick last answer is working like jQuery :)